# change column width in HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css

**UPDATED**: my real case:

I need to change the column width, I am using the inline CSS, here comes my example:

`Table` was set to `100%`, `<table width=100% ...>`

Total number of columns is **14**, few columns have `colspan = 2`.

This is my html/css issue:  after the row cell has been filled the content, the column header width changes, too. The first column has lots of space, but the 2nd column (with `colspan =2`) shrinks because of the content. Like below:

[image]

As you can see here, the first column should shrink little bit, and `Prev QA` column should expand.

What I need to change is shrink the first column and expand the 2nd column width, but no matter what I changed or added `width` to `td`, it does not affect the layout. Any body knows? Thanks in advance.

**Table:**
`<table width=800...>`

**First row:** `<tr border=0><td style='cellspacing =0; ' border=0 colspan=12 style='font-family: Calibri;Bold; font-size: 14pt; color: white; font-weight:bold; background-color:#0d384f;' width=100%>Title</td><td style='cellspacing =0; ' border=0 colspan=2 align='right' style='font-family: Calibri;Bold; font-size: 14pt; color: white; font-weight:bold; background-color:#175072;'>title2</td></tr>"`

**Second row (Header row) (need to change)**

`<tr BGCOLOR=\"#1b629b\"> <td style= \"font-weight:bold\";width=100><font color=white><Center> Client Name</Center></td><td style= \"font-weight:bold\"><font color=white><Center>Engagement</Center></td><td style= \"font-weight:bold\"><font color=white><Center>DataFreq</Center></td><td style= \"font-weight:bold\";colspan=2><font color=white><Center>Prev QA Account Balance </Center></td><td style= \"font-weight:bold\";colspan=2><font color=white><Center>Current QA Account Balance</Center></td></td><td style= \"font-weight:bold\";colspan=2><font color=white><Center>Prev QA ATB Balance </Center></td><td  style= \"font-weight:bold\";colspan=2><font color=white><Center>Current QA ATB Balance</Center><td style= \"font-weight:bold\"><font color=white><Center>Max Admit Date </Center></td><td style= \"font-weight:bold\"> <font color=white><Center>Max Charge Date</Center></td><td style= \"font-weight:bold\"><font color=white><Center>Max Trans Date </Center></td>")`

Comment: show all your code, html css

Comment: @DanielH I will paste the main part

Comment: @DanielH its too long to show correctly, is there any way I could paste? and I will doing this in c#

Comment: why does it have three columns? and just show the rendered html of the offending table - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: @LONG just the rendered HTML, and related css (inspect in your browser)

Comment: @DanielH, it is an email, can I do that, too?

Comment: @LONG **only include** what is necessary to replicate the issue. So that means enough markup to replicate what you have in your image.

Comment: Updated the image

Comment: looks like your table is sharing out the widths equally between your header columns, why not just give widths to your body columns to sort it out?

Comment: @Pete, I tried, I will paste the header html/CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i'm understanding the question correctly, all you need is to specify the width of each column in a `<col>` tag:

```
<table width='100%'>
   <col width='30%'> <!--This is for the first column-->
   <col width='40%'> <!--This is for the second column-->
   <col width='40%'> <!--This is for the third column-->
<!--input table data here -->
</table>
```

for your spanned heading, it should automatically use the combined width of the second and third column.

Comment: @LONG updated my answer with an explanation of how it should work

Comment: should I specify for all the columns? in my real case, it has 14 columns

Comment: @LONG From what i recall, and someone may correct me, the first tag will apply to the first column, the second tag to the second column, etc. you should be able to set any columns to `width='auto'` if you're not worried about that particular column resizing.

Comment: should I specify all? if I have 14 columns, do I need set for each? and total should be 100%?

Comment: @LONG yes, specify for all. if you specify the width for each column, it should add to 100%. any columns that you want to allow it to adjust on its own, specify the width as "auto". Browsers will divide out the remaining width as needed.

Comment: @LONG here is a fiddle i did up with your code if it helps https://jsfiddle.net/r0tpqmvd/